# How to use inline styles instead of classes for color and background-color in quill editor

Tags: html, css, quill

The color and background-color do not apply properly to content that is shown outside of quill editor. For example, I use the html content to send out emails, and the colors do not work in the emails sent out.

I found out that The color and background-color are applied to content with quill's own classes, while other settings (i.e. font-size) apply with inline styles.

What can I do to make quill use inline styles for color and background-color as well?

[image: devtools screenshot about how quill class applies]

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for the product suggests that this is an easy task.
There is an interactive playground which demonstrates how this should be done.
[You can see this here.](https://quilljs.com/playground/#class-vs-inline-style)

In reality, the task is far from simple. Saving html with purely inline styles, rather than proprietary class style definitions, for persistence, then re-use as templates for email or other messaging implementations, you would have thought was a fairly common requirement.

If you want to do this, be prepared for hours of frustration.

Switching off the insertion of class into html is fairly straight forward, as the documentation suggests, and getting Quill editor to insert inline styles into the html is fairly straight-forward.

[image]

So your html becomes:
[image]

So far, so good.
Once you begin to customise the toolbar options, it then becomes problematic.
Using the example in the documentation, you will quickly find that the edtor no longer inserts the inline styling:
[image]